# register custom builder globally in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel

I've implemented `https://gist.github.com/tonila/26f6a82c4dbe63d93b22ac67eaee2d6d` <- this custom builder into my project, which is for mass insert or update data. But it is not re-useable. If i want to use it again to other controllers i had to import `CustomBuilder` and `CustomGrapher` classes and include this 2 lines again and again.

```
$builder = new CustomBuilder(app('db')->connection(), new CustomGrammar());
$builder->from('some_items')->insertOrUpdate($request->all());
```

So is there any way I can register it globally so I can call it from any model, like `Model::insertOrupdate()`or using query builder like `DB::table('table_name')->insertOrUpdate()`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make a directory in the app folder, call it for example `Helpers` then make a new file called `CustomBuilder.php` and another one called `CustomGrammar.php`, then change the namespace to `App\Helpers`, finally call it in your controller.

```
$builder = new CustomBuilder(app('db')->connection(), new CustomGrammar());
$builder->from('some_items')->insertOrUpdate($request->all());
```